# Rails: Cant change hover color?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

When I hover this link:

```
<div id="withLibre">
    by <%= link_to p.user.username, "#", {class: "username_link"} %><%=time_ago_in_words(p.created_at) %> ago 
</div>
```

...the background color is black, even if I set the `background-color` to `none` or another color. I am able to change the `color`, but not the `background-color`. The CSS is presented here:

```
.username_link:hover{
    background-color: none;
    color: #34DDDD;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you have some scaffolding CSS file in your assets folder.

Comment: Yes, I do. I tried to delete it, but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you do not intent to use the scaffolding CSS then you can delete, the problem most likely is that you're having a clash of your style with the generated by the scaffolding.

Comment: Use Chrome dev tools or Firebug to see what css rule is being applied and where it come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe is a "priority" issue. Try this:

```
#withLibre .username_link:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #34DDDD;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

or `background-color: transparent !important;`.

Comment: Edited: `background-color: transparent;` because `none` is not a valid value.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Suddenly I could change the background-color too, hmmm? anyways it worked :) Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

remove from your project "scaffold.css.scss",. This file contains styles for anchors that cause the issue:

```
a {
  color: #000;
  &:visited {
    color: #666;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
}
```

Or delete this snipped form scaffold.css.scss file

Second, remove "{}" that surrounds class: ....,But I don't really know if this is an typo

```
<%= link_to p.user.username, "#", class: "username_link" %>
```

Good luck.